# (PIL / Pillow) Text in wrong position despite having correct coordinates

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

So the plan here is to have a bot send a message in a specific channel when a user gets a role.
That message contains an image made in PIL — It has username and avatar fetched from Discord — and a text welcoming the user with some basic channel instructions.

This is the code I have thus far.

```
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(808176065519812638)
        general_channel = guild.get_channel(808176065519812641)

        url = requests.get(member.avatar_url)
        avatar = Image.open(BytesIO(url.content)).convert("RGB")
        avatar = avatar.resize((240, 240))
        bigsize = (avatar.size[0] * 3, avatar.size[1] * 3)
        mask = Image.new("L", bigsize, 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=240)
        mask = mask.resize(avatar.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        avatar.putalpha(mask)

        output = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(1500, 396))
        output.putalpha(mask)
        output.save("avatar.png")

        img = Image.open("welcomebeta.png")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        text = f"{member.name}"
        textcaps = text.upper()
        font = ImageFont.truetype("roboto-boldcondensed.ttf", 118)
        draw.text((485, 152), textcaps, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
        img.paste(avatar, (152, 82), avatar)
        img.save("welcome_user.png")

        file = discord.File("welcome_user.png")
        channel = self.client.get_channel(808176065519812641)
        await channel.send(file=file)
        guild = self.client.get_guild(808176065519812638)
        channel = guild.get_channel(808176065519812641)

        await channel.send(
            f"<:lfcwave:808558627371614258> Welcome to This Server {member.mention} <:lfcwave:808558627371614258> \nIf you have any general inquiries about the server, players, or discord settings, please do not hesitate to ask! Go to <#808559611207483392> to unlock more channels. Read <#808559377648451595> if u wanna talk transfers. If it's matchday <#808451284914929694> will be open for you to get the match roles. If it's another team playing use <#808559425379237898> and feel free to join in our score prediction challenge here <#808559459664265226>"
        )
        await self.client.send(channel, "welcome_user.png")
```

[Here is what I aim to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDXlw.png)

Now the problem here is that when I run the bot the written text for the username is not in the correct place. I have checked multiple times using the ruler on Photoshop and its coordinates are (485.3, 155.3).

After that, I compared it with the coordinates on python. From what I understand, it does not accept integers, but 0.3 px difference shouldn't be as huge as it is in the returned image. They do approximately match in numbers, but for some reason, it still is in the wrong place.

I opened the returned image from the bot, and the coordinates for the misplaced text is (491.5 ,177.5)

[This is the current result of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQh5r.png)

I used an alt account to see how the text would look with longer usernames. I also am trying to find a way if it is possible for the text to automatically be resized when it is a long username in order to avoid the username taking the whole image.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually made a similar system a while ago, for one my discord bots.

Here's some code that does what you're looking for:

```py
def GetTextDimensions(text, points, font):
    class SIZE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("cx", ctypes.c_long), ("cy", ctypes.c_long)]

    hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    hfont = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateFontA(-points, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, font)
    hfont_old = ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont)
    size = SIZE(0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetTextExtentPoint32A(hdc, text.encode('cp1252'), len(text), ctypes.byref(size))
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont_old)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.DeleteObject(hfont)
    return (size.cx, size.cy)


def resizetofit(text,sz,fontname,max_horizontal):
    while True:
        width, height = GetTextDimensions(text, sz, fontname) #Get size of text
        if width < max_horizontal: #Check if text is small enough
            break
        else: #And if not, make it one point smaller
            sz -= 1
    return width,height,sz


width, height, size = resizetofit("TEXT", DEFAULT_SIZE, "FONT NAME", MAX_HORIZONTAL) #Find the correct size for text
font = ImageFont.truetype("PATH TO FONT.ttf", size=size) #Get the font for PIL
x_pos = DEFAULT_X_POSITION
x = x_pos - (width / 2) #Center the position, using the width of the resized text
y = Y_POSITION
draw.text((x, y), name, (255,255,255), font=font) #Draw the text
```

Little Example using discord.py:

```py
def GetTextDimensions(text, points, font):
    class SIZE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("cx", ctypes.c_long), ("cy", ctypes.c_long)]

    hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    hfont = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateFontA(-points, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, font)
    hfont_old = ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont)
    size = SIZE(0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetTextExtentPoint32A(hdc, text.encode('cp1252'), len(text), ctypes.byref(size))
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont_old)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.DeleteObject(hfont)
    return (size.cx, size.cy)


def resizetofit(text, sz, fontname, max_horizontal):
    while True:
        width, height = GetTextDimensions(text, sz, fontname)  # Get size of text
        if width < max_horizontal:
            break
        else:
            sz -= 1
    return width, height, sz

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("Shrekify"):
        name = message.author.name
        image = Image.open("shrek1.png")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        width, height, size = resizetofit(name, 100, "Roboto-Bold", 948) #In this example all the values have been filled out, for example, in this case, the max horizontal value is the horizontal size of the image
        font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Bold.ttf", size=size)
        x_pos = 474 #And here i want the text centered, so i use the middle of the image
        x = x_pos - (width / 2)
        y = 40
        draw.text((x, y), name, fill=color, font=font)
        image.save("shrek1text.png")
        shrekimg = discord.File("shrek1text.png")
        await message.channel.send(file=shrekimg)
```

This example uses rewrite

Comment: Thanks for answering one of the questions! Yeah, it's a bit confusing to me since I'm new into this. What confuses me is how I can incorporate that code into the one above. I can understand some of the code though.

Comment: made it (hopefully) less confusing

Comment: That looks a lot better! So the idea here is to post this code under the `@commands.Cog.listener() async def on_member_join(self, member):` ? that's the main part that confuses me because I see lot of `def` but I never worked with a command that has more than a function let alone an event. I'm really thankful for the help so far!

Comment: I added an example to try and make it easier to understand

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience! Now It is a lot easier to understand. Now I'm trying to find the reason why  it gives this error `width, height, size = resizetofit(name, 396, "Roboto-Bold", 1500)  NameError: name 'resizetofit' is not defined`But yeah there's definitely some progress!

Comment: it means you haven't defined `resizetofit`, or in other words: either the piece of code that executed the function is executed before the function's definition, or the function isn't defined at all

Comment: That's odd. https://i.imgur.com/C8HnJa4.png The definition of the function is above the code that executes

Comment: you added the `self` argument, so to call the function, you have to use `self.resizetofit`

Comment: Oh, and you'll also have to edit the resizetofit function, since you added the self argument to `GetTextDimensions`, you'll have to change the function call to `self.GetTextDimensions`

Comment: The code works! Now the issue I'm having here is how I can correctly adjust the numbers. https://i.imgur.com/G2BXV0T.png 

I drew so it would make it easier to explain and to understand what I'm trying to achieve https://i.imgur.com/Ryh4eAZ.jpeg

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: You've already calculated the max horizontal size (589), the x position should be the center of the text: `leftmostx + maxhorizontal / 2`, which in this case is `455 + 589 / 2` , which is 749.5 (you'll have to round it to 750 or 749), and the y position should be the y position you were using before (or you can calculate where it should be like the x position)

Comment: It's almost there! https://i.imgur.com/FLy1YTN.png Even though the max horizontal size is set to (589) the name does not resize to that. Also, I had to adjust the y because it wouldn't be at the correct place so I adjusted it to 135 by trial & error. This is the current code that gave the image shown above https://i.imgur.com/xgDs8ET.png

Comment: try printing the width, so we can try to debug it

Comment: It printed the number 587